# removing image from an array of images displayed in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an imageView in a collection view which is populated by adding images from camera of gallery through an array. I am able to add the images to array now I want to remove images when a button is tapped. This button is present on every collectionView cell. The issue I have now is when ever I try to remove this image from the array, the application crashes `index out of range` or removes all the cells.

`var imageDataArray: [UIImage] = []`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PicturesCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.setup(image: imageDataArray[indexPath.item], indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

extension PicturesVC: PictureDelegate {
    func removeImage(index: Int) {
        print("Button Tapped g11 \(index)")
        imageDataArray.remove(at: index)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

my cell

```
class PicturesCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var propertyImage: UIImageView!
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    weak var delegate: PictureDelegate?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setup(image: UIImage, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        propertyImage.image = image
        removeImg(indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func removeImg(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        deleteBtn.rx.tap
            .asDriver().drive(onNext: {
                self.delegate?.removeImage(index: indexPath.item)
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }

}
```

Comment: If this is rxswift or whatever it's called, you need to include that in your tags.

Comment: Keeping an array of images in memory it is definitely not a good idea

Comment: Okay @matt the only rxSwift there is the tap which could easily be replaced by adding target to the Button

Comment: @LeoDabus what do you suggest please

Comment: Just keep the image URLs